# Flutter : problem with creating a document in firestore with riverhooks

Tags: flutter, hook, flutter-provider, riverpod

whenever i want to make a document in firestore it wo't let me , i think its something that i did with riverpod and with hooks
here is the code :

```
onPressed: () async {
                                    currentOrganization.when(
                                        data: (organization) async {
                                          _post.value = _post.value
                                              .copyWith(creator: organization);
                                          print(_post.value);

                                          String imageid = uuid.v4();
                                          pickedImage = await ImagePicker()
                                              .getImage(
                                                  source: ImageSource.gallery,
                                                  maxWidth: 1920,
                                                  maxHeight: 1200,
                                                  imageQuality: 80);
                                          Reference reference = FirebaseStorage
                                              .instance
                                              .ref()
                                              .child("$imageid");
                                          UploadTask uploadTask = reference
                                              .putFile(File(pickedImage.path));
                                          await uploadTask.then((res) async {
                                            imageUrl = await reference
                                                .getDownloadURL();
                                          });
                                          _post.value = _post.value
                                              .copyWith(picture: imageUrl);
                                        },
                                        loading: () =>
                                            const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                        error: (error, stack) => Center(
                                              child: Text("$error"),
                                            ));
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  context
                                      .read(createPostUSeCaseProvider)
                                      .execute(CreatePostUseCaseInput(
                                          uuid.v4(),
                                          _post.value.description,
                                          _post.value.title,
                                          _post.value.creator,
                                          _post.value.likes,_post.value.picture))
                                      .then(
                                        (result) => result.fold(
                                          (failure) {
                                            print('FAILURE: $failure');
                                            toast("Please try again");
                                          },
                                          (unit) {
                                            toast(" successfully");
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      );
                                },
```

when i delete the `currentOrganizationProvider` everything works like charm

here is the
***UseCase***

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:takaful/application/core/use_cases/i.use_case.dart';
import 'package:takaful/application/post/use_case/create_post/create_post.input.dart';
import 'package:takaful/application/providers/post.repository.provider.dart';
import 'package:takaful/domain/core/i.failure.dart';
import 'package:takaful/domain/model/post.dart';
import 'package:takaful/domain/post/i.post.repository.dart';

final createPostUSeCaseProvider = Provider((ref) =>
    CreatePostUseCase(postRepository: ref.watch(postRepositoryProvider)));

class CreatePostUseCase implements IUseCase<CreatePostUseCaseInput, Unit> {
  final IPostRepository _postRepository;

  CreatePostUseCase({IPostRepository postRepository})
      : _postRepository = postRepository;

  @override
  Future<Either<IFailure, Unit>> execute(input) async {
    return await _postRepository.createPost(
        description: input.discreption,
        model: input.model,
        id: input.id,
        title: input.title,
        likes: input.likes,
        picture: input.picture);
  }
}
```

and the
***infrastructure code*** :

```
Future<Either<UserFailures, Unit>> createPost({String id, String title, String description, OrganizationModel model, int likes,String picture}) async{
       try {
      await _firestore.collection(collection).doc().set({
        "id":id,
        "title":title,
        "description":description,
        "creator":model,
        "likes":likes,
        "picture":picture
      });
      return right(unit);
    } catch (error) {
      return left(UserFailures.serverError());
    }
  }
```

when i delete the the provider everything works , any idea , and i need the model !

Comment: you say that you fixed it when removing currentOrganizationProvider, can you show what does that provider do? Also you have a problem with the onPressed or the onTap of the GestureDetector?

Comment: iam so sorry i've forgot to delete the question , i've successfully managed to solve it